# How to find out the duplicate characters in a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I take a string with integer count

```
int count=0;
string s="wow"
```

and i am using foreach loop to count number of characters in a  specified string

```
foreach(char ch in s)
{

count++
}
```

so how can i count those characters which are repeated in my string like 'w'.

Comment: @xanatos Honestly, title and question say different things. Title says; _how to find duplicate characters_ but question says _how to count duplicate characters_. But seems like both doesn't covered in the duplicate question. Re-opened. My bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this )

```
string test = "aababc";
        var result = test.GroupBy(c => c).Where(c => c.Count() > 1).Select(c => new { charName = c.Key, charCount = c.Count()});
```

Answer (score 4):

Do like this

```
  string s="wow";
  int repeats= s.Length - s.ToCharArray().Distinct().Count();
```